# how to manage Kerberos Authentication Issues in a Reporting Services 2008 r2 Environment

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I have few ssrs 2008 reports.I have created group of users and gave all required permissions to that group.

Now when I am running those reports I am getting strange error.

**Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'**

I don't know from where it came.

I got suggestion that its a issue related to Kerberos authentication. Please some one knows how to solve this let me know.

Or some one knows to solve this kerberos issue also tell me in steps if possible.

Thanks

Vik

Comment: Could be a [double hop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx) problem.

Comment: Can you please give the solution for that

Comment: The double hop issue is with NTLM. Can you tell us more about the architecture? You're using SSRS but that can be deployed in a number of different ways. Is the user accessing through the standard report manager or through SharePoint or through a custom web front end of some sort?

Comment: User is accessing through standard report manager http://servername/reports. In dev environment reports are working fine. even users can access them. But in test environment I am getting this annoymous logon error.

Comment: reports have created in ssrs 2008 r2. Deployed in specified dev and test servers. In dev working fine but with the same permissions I am getin error in test.

Answer (score 0):

Are your reports using pass-through integrated authentication, defined user integrated authentication, or sql user authentication? I suspect the first, in which case you're dealing with the difference between impersonation and delegation.

When connecting to a web server using integrated authentication, behind the scenes you are actually using NTLM or Kerberos. Both allow the process running your web server to act as you. NTLM's impersonation via security token prevents the server from connecting to yet *another* server as you (that is, to the DB server) and there acting as you again—this is the "double-hop" problem. Kerberos instead uses delegation, passing a ticket around that each server can check for validity and allow.

To get Kerberos working there are several requirements.

- If you're connecting to the web server using a name other than its main DNS name (using as an alias) you have to register the alias as valid for the machine with SetSPN. You can have problems with the SPN (Service Principal Name) even without this. Check the SPN on your servers carefully to see if it matches what you expect.
- The server you initially connect to must be "trusted for delegation" in your domain policy.
- The user that your web server is running under must be "trusted for delegation" as well.

You can work around all this stuff by just making your reports have stored credentials of some sort rather than using pass-through authentication.

The difference between dev and test could be the IIS user, or the data source.

Now, I am assuming here that you're not using SharePoint and are just doing a normal SSRS web install. So if that is not correct please say so.